Resolve ProviderToken<SomeComponent> to SomeComponent
I have ProviderToken<SomeComponent> but I need actual <SomeComponent> to be able to feed it into the viewContainerRef.createComponent(SomeComponent).
Is there a way to "convert" ProviderToken<SomeComponent> to <SomeComponent>?

can you give exact example of your issue? Because from what you described I don't see any problem - you can straight up do viewContainerRef.createComponent(SomeComponent), and you don't even need ProviderToken for that

@MG the issue is that i don't have SomeComponent. All I have is a method that returns ProviderToken<SomeComponent> and from that, I need to get to SomeComponent itself to be able to feed it into createComponent.

You don't need instance of component for viewContainerRef, you only need type. What is SomeComponent in your case? Is it specific type? Do you not know this type on compilation time? Please provide example with code

@MG I know I don't need an instance of the type but only a type. And yes, I don't know that type at compile time. All I have a function call that returns ProviderToken.

@tlzg please share the minimal reproducible code!

I hope you are looking for this piece of code
component = inject(COMPONENT_TOKEN) // inject the component by token

showComponent() {
  viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.component); // use injected component to render
}

// somewhere in the injection tree
providers: [ {provide: COMPONENT_TOKEN, useValue: MyDynamicComponent}]

